# How to get first and last name without access token?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

According to the FB SDK docs, it appears that some data from the response object I should be able to retrieve sans access token. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)  However when I do this, I receive the message in the response object -

```
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

Does anyone have any insight on the matter?

Thanks a ton!

EDIT - the code I'm using:

```
function testAPI() {
                console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                    console.log(response);
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My finding so far indicate that basic information cannot be accessed unless one has either 'userid' or 'username' as in this post.

If one has to try and fetch basic information using following url, then access_token is needed

[facebook](http://graph.facebook.com/me)

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```